# ¿Es correcto decir "¿Cómo se tutea?"?

Tags: gramática, diferencias-regionales, sintaxis

Quiero aprender cómo se usa la palabra "tú" en una región (por ejemplo, el uso de la palabra es diferente en España y en América Latina, y quiero preguntar sobre esta diferencia).  ¿Puedo decirle lo siguiente a una persona en la región, y me entenderá?  ¿Es idiomático?

> ¿Cómo se tutea (aquí/en México/...)?

Comment: No me queda claro si quieres una explicación de cómo se tutearía según la región (en cuyo caso te recomiendo elegir una y poner la etiqueta correspondiente) o si quieres saber si esa es una pregunta que puedes formular a un paisano de la zona donde vayas para que te ayude a entender como se tutea en la región donde os encontráis.

Comment: @Diego: Quiero saber si puedo decir esa pregunta a una persona y esa persona me entenderá.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Tutear*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=azNQE9X) es un verbo que designa el uso del *tú* en una conversación entre personas. Es, por tanto, un verbo claramente definido y que solo tiene una forma de hacerse. Es decir, no se tutea de una forma u otra, sino que directamente se tutea (o no).

Por tanto, al decir:

> ¿Cómo se tutea (aquí/en México/con tu suegra/...)?

El uso de *cómo* hace que parezca que estamos preguntando por la forma de tuteo, lo que no tiene sentido.
Suena más correcto preguntar si es pertinente *tutear* en un contexto o lugar dado:

> ¿Se tutea (aquí/en México/con tu suegra/...)?
>
> ¿Es posible tutear (aquí/en México/con tu suegra/...)?

Answer (score 2):

"¿Cómo se tutea aquí?" no es una pregunta con una única respuesta posible ni tan sencilla de responder. Formulada así suena un poco rara y probablemente haga que el interlocutor conteste solicitando una aclaración, pero si se la entiende como "¿En qué ocasiones es correcto tutear a una persona aquí?" o "¿A quiénes se puede o no se puede tratar con el pronombre informal aquí?", las posibilidades son variadas.

- En España se puede elegir entre *tú* y *usted*, y en plural, entre *vosotros* y *ustedes*.
- En buena parte de Latinoamérica la elección es entre *tú* y *usted*, en singular, pero sólo existe *ustedes* en plural (y *ustedes* es neutro en cuanto a su grado de formalidad o familiaridad).
- En muchas regiones de Latinoamérica existe otro pronombre informal de segunda persona singular, *vos*, además de *tú*, y las reglas o costumbres que dictan cuál usar en cada caso son diferentes.
- En ciertas regiones se usa *usted* como pronombre familiar, íntimo, de manera contraria a las expectativas habituales en otros dialectos, donde *usted* implica distanciamiento o formalidad.
- En la región rioplatense (sur de Uruguay, zona litoral de Argentina) prácticamente no se usa el *tú* sino sólo el *vos*, aunque el verbo para designar el uso del registro informal sigue siendo *tutear* (existe *vosear* pero es un término técnico lingüístico). En esta región además el tratamiento informal es usado con mucha más frecuencia que en otras partes.
- La conjugación de los verbos en las regiones donde se usa *vos* suelen diferir entre sí. En Argentina se dice *vos cantás / vos comés*, en Chile se dice *vos cantái / vos comís*, y en ciertas partes de Uruguay puede decirse *tú cantás / tú comés*.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Nótese, sin embargo, que el autor de la pregunta no pregunta por los lugares en los que se tutea, sino por la corrección de la frase. Seguramente tu respuesta encajaría muy bien en ['vos' vs 'tú' usage by country](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui Es cierto. Pensé más en aclarar tu otra respuesta, en el sentido de que no siempre tutear a alguien implica lo mismo. De todas formas lo mío es un resumen muy parcial.

Comment: Entiendo. Y agradezco la carga de profundidad que le das, pues en base a tu respuesta sí podría tener sentidio preguntar _¿cuál es la forma de tutear en X lugar o en la situación Y?_.