# What is the conjugation "Querés"

Tags: verbos, argentina, voseo

I was recently on an Argentinian website and saw:

> Querés abonar y no sabés cómo?

It looks like it's saying "do you want to pay but don't know how?" but that's assuming it were "quieres" and not "querés". I can't seem to find this conjugation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the *vos* form used for the second person in some parts of the Spanish speaking world and that includes Argentina. If you go to the dictionary of the RAE https://dle.rae.es/?w=diccionario and type in the verb where it tells you to write in the word you want to look up that will then give you a definition of the word plus a button marked *conjugar* to display the conjugation.

For more information about *voseo* this question is a good start ['Vos' vs 'tú' usage by country](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25/vos-vs-t%c3%ba-usage-by-country) and we also have a tag for it [voseo](/questions/tagged/voseo)

Answer (score 0):

in Argentina, we say in Affirmative Simple Present
"Vos querés" instead of "Tu quieres".

The same form is used in negative and interrogative.

Vos no querés ir a la escuela. Instead of "Tu no quieres ir a la escuela."
¿Vos querés ir a la escuela? Instead of "¿Tu quieres ir a la escuela?"

Vos is casual and means proximity, it is opposite to Usted.

Usted is used meaning respect and distance, for example when a young person is talking to an adult, or when a student is talking to a professor.

Profesor Pérez, ¿usted quiere que yo lea este artículo?

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Tu is also informal right? in which case it's a question of where you're speaking spanish?