# “sos importante” vs “eres importante”?

Tags: gramática, voseo

I was wondering about how to tell someone but I think they are important. I started off wrongly saying “**estás importante**” but I understand that “**eres importante**” is correct.

What I don’t understand is the phrase “**sos importante**,” which my friend who is a native Spanish speaker told me is most correct.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference if you want to find verb forms you can use the dictionary of the Real Academia. So if you look up *ser* which is the infinitive and then press the button marked *conjugar* you will get the full conjugation. Here it is https://dle.rae.es/ser?m=form#conjugaciongZoQ72j

You will see that it gives two second person familiar singular forms *tú / vos* and alongside them *eres / sos* the corresponding verb forms. The use of *vos* is called, not surprisingly *voseo* and we have a tag for it [voseo](/questions/tagged/voseo) which will give you more information. As for the coverage of it [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25/vos-vs-t%c3%ba-usage-by-country) and answers discuss which countries in Latin America use *vos*.

Comment: + 1 but Basically, it Argentina and Uruguay and some parts of Chile. Why not just say that?

Comment: @Lambie because *voseo* is used in Argentina, Paraguay, Uruguay, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Bolivia, Chile, Colombia, Ecuador, Panama, Venezuela

Comment: Mostly cono sur, mostly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is the same, but "sos importante" is commonly used in countries like Argentina. I don't know if it used in other South American countries but definitely used in Argentina.

Comment: It is also used in the some regions of Colombia that use *voseo*

Comment: @DGaleano Oh I didn't know, thank you for the info :)